# How to correctly re-use pointer object to custom class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, delete-operator

I have a lot of code so I am going to try to do this with as little as possible to show you guys.

I am writing a program that is leaking memory, my efforts of cleaning up memory is causing my program to crash (only in Visual Studio, not using MinGw). I am using Visual Studio 2015 to debug my code, and see how much memory I am using. However, when adding the `delete` keyword to try to free up some memory Visual Studio triggers a breakpont. When following the breakpoint to try and figure out whats wrong, VS takes me to a page that says 'No Source Available'.

Compiling this same code with MinGw gcc works find and executes fine, however I need Visual Studio's debugger so I can see my memory usage so that I can determine if the leak is fixed or not.

I am creating a lot of objects dynamically and re assigning new objects to them, I need help figuring out how to delete the old memory so I can only keep in memory the newly created object.

Here is the code that I am concerned with

```
StateNode *initState = nullptr;                 // Pointer to the initial state
StateNode *finishState = nullptr;               // Pointer to the final state
bool finished = false;                          // Flag for checking if the puzzle has completed    

size = getNumQueens();

// Make dynamic 2D array of the specified size
char** init = new char*[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    init[i] = new char[size];


// Puzzle main loop
while (!finished)
{       
    // Randomize the queens placement on the board
    randomizeGame(init, size);

    // Make the initial state with the current game board
    initState = new StateNode(init, size);

    // Run the hillclimbing algo
    finishState = HillClimbing<StateNode>::Run(initState, size);

    // Check to see if the algo returned a valid end state
    if (finishState->getHeuristic() == 0)
        finished = true;
    else
    {
        // Try to clean up memory to prevent memory leak
        delete initState;    // This is where Visual Studio throws breakpoint
        delete finishState;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this while loop constantly creates new `StateNode` objects by assigning them to initState. Also, the `HillClimbing::Run()` method returns a dynamically created StateNode and assigns it to finishState.

Without this code:

```
else
    {
        // Try to clean up memory to prevent memory leak
        delete initState;    // This is where Visual Studio throws breakpoint
        delete finishState;
    }
```

My program leaks a lot of memory, approaching 2GB when the program crashes.
With those lines VS throws breakpoints, but MinGw gcc does not, and the program works a lot faster.

My main question: How can I correctly manage the memory of `initState` and `finishState` to fix memory leaks.

i.e. How can I only keep in memory one `StateNode` object, while deleting all other instances as I go.

**EDIT**
This is what is in the VS output window

```
The thread 0x4244 has exited with code 1857355776 (0x6eb50000).
HEAP[N-Queens.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 01230000,     0126B540 )
N-Queens.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

When going into the dissasembly and pressing F11 to keep going through the code, eventually this happens:
[image]

**EDIT 2**

StateNode.h

```
class StateNode
{
    private:
        char** state;
        int heuristic;
        int size;

    public:
        StateNode(char** state, int size);
        int getHeuristic();
        void printState();
        char** getState();
};
```

Here is the code for StateNode.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "state-node.h"
#include "heuristic.h"

/* Constructor, accepts a state and a size (the number of queens) */
StateNode::StateNode(char ** state, int size)
{
    this->state = state;
    this->size = size;
    this ->heuristic = NQueens::CalcHeuristic(state, size);
}



/* Returns the heuristic value of the node */
int StateNode::getHeuristic()
{
    return this->heuristic;
}

/* Prints the state with a nice like board for better visualization */
void StateNode::printState()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        std::cout << " ____";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->size; j++)
        {
            if (j < this->size - 1)
            {

                std::cout << "| " << state[i][j] << "  ";

            }
            else
            {

                std::cout << "| " << state[i][j] << "  |";

            }

        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < this->size; k++)
            std::cout << "|____";
        std::cout << "|\n";
    }
}

/* Returns a copy of the nodes state */
char ** StateNode::getState()
{
    return state;
}
```

Comment: What's in the VS Output window when it stops on the delete?  There are a variety of corrupt memory situations that will cause VS to stop during a delete/memory free.  Usually you've clobbered some sentinel values before or after allocated memory.

Comment: Are all your functions recompiled from source in your project?  Or do they live in other libraries (e.g. DLLs).  If they live in other libraries, you may be running into the issue where memory is allocated in a DLL but your are freeing it in main which may use a different runtime.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm see my edit

Comment: @Anon Mail I am not using any external DLL's. only the source I created for this project.

Comment: `Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap` indicates that the memory you're trying to free hasn't been allocated.  Which could mean that your initstate value has been clobbered, or there could be other problems elsewhere that corrupt the heap and this free is when the validator noticed.

Comment: @BradStell in that case, I would venture a guess that something wrong is happening inside the two functions.  Perhaps the StateNode pointers they return are not correct.

Comment: @Anon Mail The only reason I suspect this is not the case is that the program runs perfect and executes with expected results using MinGw on the command line. My algorithm solves the puzzle and works fine.

Comment: What is the correct way to manage the memory of these objects so that I can keep reusing the pointers?

Comment: Check your accesses to `init` and init[]` to be sure your not going one-past-the-end.  VS is aggressive in tracking memory overwrites when building for debugging.  The other compiler might not be and/or int might allocate more memory so the overwrites don't cause a problem.  The code you've posted has no obvious problems.

Comment: *What is the correct way to manage the memory of these objects* --  Instead of using old-style C++, use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays,.and smart pointers for resource management.

Comment: Using a vector in this application would be hard (all my logic is done by looping through 2D arrays). I tried using smart pointers but couldn't find a good enough tutorial on how to use them, and I just broke my code.

Comment: Once a 2d vector is declared, all the code you currently have that loop through 2d arrays remains.  A vector has `operator [ ]` that gives you the same results as an arrays `[ ]`.  Also, it isn't "hard" -- just declare the vector, fix the compiler errors, and the code will work.

Comment: Also, please post `StateNode`.  If it does not manage resources, then there probably is no need whatsoever for pointers.  However, your general problem is that you're throwing around dynamically allocated memory without any coherent sense of who owns the pointers.  For example, `Run` function allocates memory, but the responsibility of who maintains that pointer is not clear.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie First I did not know of 2D vectors, I will look into this. But this does not address the `StateNode` objects that I need to re-use. Look at my edit 2, I added my `StateNode` code

Comment: So `StateNode` contains a `char**`?  If so, then this whole exercise can be solved by using `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`, and instead of pointers, just pass back values or references.  No need to call `new` at all.  Also, what  you should post is the `StateNode` header so we can see the member types.

Comment: So to make sure I understand you: Change the char** to 2d vector. Then do not instantiate the `StateNode` object dynamically, but instead on the stack?

Comment: @BradStell Yes.  The goal of a well-written C++ program is to use value/stack based values as much as possible.  Only when it is absolutely necessary (which is getting less and less these days with the facilities of C++ 11, 14, and 17), should you use naked calls to `new` and `delete`.

Comment: OK, this brings up another question. I currently reuse `initState` by reassigning it. This cannot be done with objects that are not dynamic. So how would I change my code to work around this? In my while loop I need to constantly reasign the `initState` node as well as grab the `StateNode` returned from `HillClimbing::Run()`. I do not know how to do this non dynamically.

Comment: Why do you say it can't be done non-dynamically?  Your program does not make any use of polymorphism, and I don't see an issue with object lifetimes.  So from what I see it *can* be done non-dynamically.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code allocates dynamically allocated memory, but doesn't have a coherent sense of who owns what pointer(s).  It then becomes cumbersome to figure out when, where, and who is responsible for freeing the memory.  To fix such code may require more error-prone logic to figure to attempt to straighten out the mess.

Instead of this, using C++ and "new-less" code, the following is more or less the equivalent of your current code:

```
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<std::vector<char>> Char2D;
class StateNode
{
    private:
        char2D state;
        int size;
        int heuristic;

    public:
        StateNode(const Char2D& theState, int theSize);
        int getHeuristic();
        void printState();
        Char2D& getState() { return state; }
};
```

Then your constructor lools like this:

```
StateNode::StateNode(const Char2D& theState, int theSize) :
                     state(theState), 
                     size(theSize), 
                     heuristic(NQueens::CalcHeuristic(state, size)) {}
```

Of course, your `NQueens::CalcHeuristic` has to take a `Char2D` (by reference) instead of a `char**`.

Then the rest of the implementation can look like this:

```
bool finished = false;     

size = getNumQueens();

// Make dynamic 2D array of the specified size
Char2D init(size, std::vector<char>(size));

// Puzzle main loop
while (!finished)
{       
    // Randomize the queens placement on the board
    randomizeGame(init, size);

    // Make the initial state with the current game board
    StateNode initState(init, size);

    // Run the hillclimbing algo
    finishState = HillClimbing<StateNode>::Run(initState, size);

    // Check to see if the algo returned a valid end state
    if (finishState.getHeuristic() == 0)
        finished = true;
}
```

The `initState` and `finishState` are two distinct objects.  Also, no need for the `else` block.

I know this is somewhat different than your original code, but the goal should be to use `value` types and if need be, smart pointers (which I didn't see a need here).  Using types as the aforementioned ones is one way to not have issues as your facing now.

---

If you still want to go the pointer route, I would still leave the `vector` alone, and make the following changes:

```
#include <memory>
//...
std::unique_ptr<StateNode> finishState;

// Puzzle main loop
while (!finished)
{       
    // Randomize the queens placement on the board
    randomizeGame(init, size);

    // Make the initial state with the current game board
    std::unique_ptr<StateNode> initState = std::make_unique<StateNode>(init, size);

    // Run the hillclimbing algo
    finishState.reset(HillClimbing<StateNode>::Run(initState, size));

    // Check to see if the algo returned a valid end state
    if (finishState->getHeuristic() == 0)
        finished = true;
}
```

There is no leak in this code, as we are using `std::unique_ptr`, which automatically deallocates the memory for you when either the pointer goes out of scope, or `reset` is called.

Comment: Thank you very much for this example. Let me take a minute to see if I can get my code translated over to work like this, then I will report back.

Comment: Ok, I got the code translated over and it doesn't throw any compile errors. Now I need your help with one last part of the code that now doesn't work. The method `randomizeGame` used to take in the `char**` and change the array. The vector does not seem to work this way, and my game board stays empty.

Comment: I updated the answer with a smart pointer version of your code (with the `std::vector` remaining in place in the `StateNode` object.  This is probably what you were trying to do.

Comment: Yes, Is the smart pointer method better or your first method? I have my code working with the first method (except for the issue in my above comment)

Comment: If you pass the vector by reference, then the code remains exactly the same if you're using `[ ]` to access the elements.  Otherwise you need to show your code.  The second method shows how to use a smart pointer correctly, but pointers in general are not really needed for this.

Comment: Ok, so I fixed the issue by changing the method signature to `void randomizeGame(Char2D &state, int size)` and it works now

Comment: Question: the statement `typedef std::vector<std::vector<char>> Char2D` somehow has global scope, even though it is only declared in the StateNode.h file. Why is this? Should it stay there or be moved somewhere else? If so where should if be properly located in my project?

Comment: It's a typedef, so it shouldn't do any harm, unless you had another entity called `Char2D`.  You could move that definition in the `StateNode` class and make it `public`.  However you have to say `StateNode::Char2D` if you want to declare one outside of `StateNode`.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug through no-source-available into your code. Get vs to show disassembly and f11 into next function.

Vs has debug heap with leak detection. That can help, but also cause slow down, and earlier crash.  Compile with different C runtime to gain/lose that feature.

Application verifier also has good leak detection, showing stacks of leaked allocations.  **this is what I use**

Comment: I just tried this. Unfortunately I do not understand the dissasembly, it looks like another language and does not help me very much.

Comment: My main question is not how to stop VS from triggering the breakpoint, but rather on how to correctly reuse the memory and stop the memory leak in the first place.

Comment: Just press f11 until it gets to a call.  Then it goes to source

Comment: See my added picture of what happens when i do this.

Comment: Well if I remove the 2 'delete' lines and debug my code. My memory has a steady increase in size. Very slow, yet after 5 or 10 minutes debugger time it approaches the hundres of MB's. The heap snapshot shows that I have lots of StateNode objects and int[] * objects (which each state node has).